# rpm missing dependencies on redhat

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, libraries, links

Somehow, `rpm` stopped working on my distribution of Redhat. When I type `rpm`, I see:

`rpm: error while loading shared libraries: librpm-4.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

`which rpm` points to `/bin/rpm`. And then when I type `ldd /bin/rpm`, I see:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x001ef000)
librpm-4.3.so => not found
librpmdb-4.3.so => not found
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/libselinux.so.1 (0x0099a000)
librpmio-4.3.so => not found
libpopt.so.0 => not found
libelf.so.1 => /usr/lib/libelf.so.1 (0x00384000)
libbeecrypt.so.6 => not found
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x0093c000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00677000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x0066c000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x0067e000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x00968000)
libbz2.so.1 => not found
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x0039e000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00327000)
```

So somehow it seems I'm missing (at least) this file `librpm-4.3.so`. How can I obtain it and put it in the correct folder on my machine?

Comment: Use another machine for downloading the rpm, extract it, then copy the libs to this machine.

Comment: @IporSircer copy it to where on this machine?